# Only last value from JavaScript in while loop is displayed

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on the code displaying in the while loop data received from the database. Within that code there is a form in which I added a hidden input (name="position"). I'd like to use that input to store number of pixels from the top of the window. Unfortunately, the javascript added by me, changes the value of the hidden input only in the last table in the loop. In the first tables the hidden input named "position" remains unchanged (remains empty). Could anyone please help me?

```
<?php
while ($row = $wynik->fetch_assoc()) {
?>          

<form method="post" style="margin-bottom: 0px;" onsubmit="poz()">
<input type="hidden" name="edition" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" name="position" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Edytuj" class="edytuj">
</form>

<script>
function poz() {
var position = window.pageYOffset;
document.getElementById(<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>).value = position;
}
</script>
```

Comment: When you have generated the page, have a look at the page source for the `pos()` function, there may be several of them.

Comment: Probably start by making sure there are quotes in your `getElementById`. You've remembered to put them everywhere else, but they're still missing there. Also, as just pointed out, either build separate functions for each row, or use one function that looks up which form it's being called for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an event listener to know what is clicked

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".edytuj")].forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("click",function (e) {
      var tgt = e.target;
      tgt.previousElementSibling.value=tgt.offsetTop;
    })
  });
})
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="edition" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" name="position" value="">
<input type="button" value="Edytuj" class="edytuj">
```